# Renew Gogs SSH Key via file replace?

Tags: git, docker, docker-volume, gogs

I'm running the docker version of gogs.  It is currently working with my SSH key and I want to refresh this key.  Is it possible for me to copy the new key I generated into the docker data volume that is supporting the docker configuration files directly, instead of going through the ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: as you can see in "[routes/user/setting.go](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/blob/f59500a90bd688f99cde8820274807a581eead25/routes/user/setting.go#L344)", a key is associated to a `user.ID`.

Just copying the key ([with `docker cp`](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/13171)) would only add the ssh key without registering its link to a user.